# Fuction can't be found using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and I'm not 100% sure on how the whole *frame*, *self*, etc works.

I have this:

```
class ScalesPage(Frame):
        def GetNotes():
                key = KeyEntry.get()
                intervals = ScaleEntry.get()
                WholeNotes = ['C','C#','D','D#','E','F','F#','G','G#','A','A#','B']*4
                Root = WholeNotes.index(key)
                Chromatic = WholeNotes[Root:Root+12]
                print([Chromatic[i] for i in scales[intervals]])

        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
                Frame.__init__(self, parent)
                global KeyEntry
                KeyEntry = Entry(self)
                KeyEntry.pack()
                global ScaleEntry
                ScaleEntry = Entry(self)
                ScaleEntry.pack()
                ScaleButtonEnter = Button(self, text="Enter", command=GetNotes)
                ScaleButtonEnter.pack()
```

I'm trying to make the `ScaleButtonEnter` execute `GetNotes()`, but I keep getting the error

> NameError: name 'GetNotes' is not defined

I'm assuming I'm missing something easy, but I'm just not familiar enough with tkinter to figure it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759269/calling-static-method-in-python

Comment: Also check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735392/python-class-static-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `self.GetNotes()` instead of `GetNotes()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

`command=self.GetNotes`

As using `command=self.GetNotes()` will just call the function there, While you need it to be called only when the button is pressed.

There is no need of using the parenthesis `()` and if you want to use it without any reason you will have to use `lambda`.

Like this:

`command=lambda: self.GetNotes()`