# @staticmethod when extending with c(++)

Tags: c++, python, c, extend

To create a class usable in Python is pretty straight-forward:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/54352-defining-python-class-methods-in-c/

But how to make methods static?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `METH_STATIC` flag in [PyMethodDef](http://docs.python.org/c-api/structures.html#PyMethodDef). The method will be passed NULL as the first parameter rather than an instance of the type.

```
static PyMethodDef FooMethods[] = 
{
    {"__init__", Foo_init, METH_VARARGS, 
     "doc string"},
    {"doSomething", Foo_doSomething, METH_VARARGS | METH_STATIC,
     "doc string"},
    {NULL},
};
```