# Python OOP - object has no attribute

Tags: python, class, object, python-3.x

I am attempting to learn how to program. I really do want to learn how to program; I love the building and design aspect of it. However, in Java and Python, I have tried and failed with programs as they pertain to objects, classes, methods.. I am trying to develop some code for a program, but im stumped. I know this is a simple error. However I am lost! I am hoping someone can guide me to a working program, but also help me learn (criticism is not only expected, but APPRECIATED).

```
class Converter:

    def cTOf(self, numFrom):
        numFrom = self.numFrom
        numTo = (self.numFrom * (9/5)) + 32
        print (str(numTo) + ' degrees Farenheit')
        return numTo

    def fTOc(self, numFrom):
        numFrom = self.numFrom
        numTo = ((numFrom - 32) * (5/9))
        return numTo

convert = Converter()

numFrom = (float(input('Enter a number to convert..                '))) 
unitFrom = input('What unit would you like to convert from.. ')
unitTo = input('What unit would you like to convert to..    ')

if unitFrom == ('celcius'):
    convert.cTOf(numFrom)
    print(numTo)
    input('Please hit enter..')


if unitFrom == ('farenheit'):
    convert.fTOc(numFrom)
    print(numTo)
    input('Please hit enter..')
```

Comment: And if you're going to use classes with this, might as well make those methods [static](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes and objects are tools to accomplish a task -- they allow you to encapsulate *data* or *state* with a set of methods.  However, your data is just a number.  There is no need to encapsulate the integer, so there is no need to create a class.

In other words, don't create a class because you think you should, create a class because it makes your code simpler.

```
import sys

def f_to_c(x):
    return (x - 32) * (5/9)

def c_to_f(x):
    return x * (9/5) + 32

num_from = float(input('Enter a number to convert: '))
unit_from = input('What units would you like to convert from? ')
unit_to = input('What units would you like to convert to? ')

if (unit_from, unit_to) == ('fahrenheit', 'celsius'):
    num_to = f_to_c(num_from)
elif (unit_from, unit_to) == ('celsius', 'fahrenheit'):
    num_to = c_to_f(num_from)
else:
    print('unsupported units')
    sys.exit(1)

print('{} degrees {} is {} degrees {}'
      .format(num_from, unit_from, num_to, unit_to))
```

```
Enter a number to convert: 40
What units would you like to convert from? celsius
What units would you like to convert to? fahrenheit
40.0 degrees celsius is 104.0 degrees fahrenheit
```

The `convert` object and `Converter` class don't serve any purpose, so the code is simpler and easier to read without them.

Comment: I thought it would make it simpler in the end. However, I was wrong apparently. Smaller bites next time! Thanks for the helpful answer

Answer (score 1):

1.It should be

```
def fTOc(self, numFrom):
    self.numFrom = numFrom
```

`cTOf` method has the same problem.

2.Variable `numTo` not defined

```
numTo = convert.cTOf(numFrom)
print (numTo)
```

Comment: Since `numFrom` isn't used anywhere else in the class, why make it a member variable at all?

Comment: @NullUserException You are right, I just debug the code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right.

There is no `self.numFrom` because it is your parameter. Remove the lines `numFrom =self.numFrom` and you will be fine.

Comment: `cTOf` used `self.numFrom` later.