# how to call a function in a class from main

Tags: python

I am trying to call a function defined in a class from main..how can I do that?

```
class file_process:
    def findb(self, id):
    ....  

def main():
  id = sys.argv[2]
 file_process.findb(id)//how to call findb function from main,this is giving an error
```

Comment: You need to study up on classes and python first. You are calling a *method*, and methods want to be called on class instances.

Comment: After you've learned a little more OOP, you might decide you want to make that function a static method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `finddb` is a *method*, you need to call it on an *instance* of `file_process`:

```
file_process().finddb(id)
```

I strongly urge you to study up on Python and classes, I can recommend the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/), before you continue.

Comment: Getting the error...TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) ,should it be file_process().finddb(self,id)

Comment: @user1795998: look for a `__init__` function and see what it expects. You need to pass *something* to the `file_process()` class but we can not possibly guess what without more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of your class first:

```
process = file_process()
process.findb(id)
```