# Implementing UUID as primary key

Tags: django, uuid

I need to implement UUID as primary key but I'm not sure how to do it in Django.

My code

```
class LinkRenewAd(models.Model): # This model will generate the uuid for the ad renew link
    def make_uuid(self):
        return str(uuid.uuid1().int>>64)

    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36, primary_key=True, default=make_uuid, editable=False)
    main = models.ForeignKey(Main)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField()
    date_inserted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

When I try to generate this new model on South I got the error:

```
TypeError: make_uuid() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 13):

Django 1.8 comes with a built-in [UUID field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.UUIDField)

Example:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Answer (score 8):

`self` means you need to pass in an instance. In your case, you don't have an instance, which is why you are seeing the strange error of a missing argument.

To solve your problem, move the method that generates the field of out of your model class:

```
def make_uuid():
    return str(uuid.uuid1().int>>64)

class Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=36, primary_key=True, default=make_uuid)
```

However, this is not the ideal solution. It is better to create a custom database field. As this is a common problem, there are many versions out there. I personally like [david cramer's version](https://github.com/dcramer/django-uuidfield/blob/master/uuidfield/fields.py).

Answer (score -1):

You are passing the function around, which will be called up somewhere down in `models.Charfield`, instead from some object of `LinkRenewAd`, so no instance of any object (`self`) is passed to this method , which actually expects one. So, instead, make it a [static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python), or a lambda function, or define it as a non-member of the class.