# What does ">>" and "<<" means in python?

Tags: python

I tried to find answer here, but didn't find.

What does ">>" and "<<" means in python?

Examples in interpreter:

```
In [9]: 23 >> 64
Out[9]: 0

In [10]: 23 << 64
Out[10]: 424275113695319687168L

In [11]: 1 >> 2
Out[11]: 0

In [12]: 32132345235423451 >> 2
Out[12]: 8033086308855862

In [13]: 321323452354566423451 >> 2
Out[13]: 80330863088641605862L

In [14]: 2 >> 2
Out[14]: 0

In [15]: 233 >> 2
Out[15]: 58

In [16]: 33 >> 2
Out[16]: 8

In [17]: 3 >> 2
Out[17]: 0
```

Find usage here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14854406/4436022

Comment: [Bitwise Operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

Comment: Simple bit shifting. https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<<` and `>>` are the Binary Left Shift and Binary Right Shift respectively.

The left operands value is moved left by the number of bits specified by the right operand.

Example, Code: `temp = 14 << 2`
`The variable temp has a value of 56 because 14 (00001110 in binary) shifted left two bits equals 56 (00111000 in binary).`

The left operands value is moved right by the number of bits specified by the right operand.

Example, Code: `temp = -14 >> 2
temp has a value of -4: -14 (11110010 in two's complement binary) shifted right two bits equals -4 (11111100 in two's complement binary).`

Answer (score 1):

It's *bit shift*, like in C.  Please read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations) link.

Basically `<< 1` multiplies an integer by 2 in a fast way while `>> 1` do a integer division by 2.  `<< n` is like doing `<< 1` `n` times, so it multiplies by `2**n`. In the same way, `>> n` do an integer division by `2**n`.

Technically, if you represent your numbers in [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) (as computers do), `<<` shift all the bits on the left and `>>` shifts all the bits to the right.

Thus 3, represented in binary by *(00000011)* becomes *(00001100)* when applied with `<<2`.  *(00001100)* is the representation of 12.  Again, `3>>1` shift *(00000011)* to *(00000001)* which is `1`, the same result as `3 div 2`.

Answer (score 0):

These operators are bit shift :

- `>>` shifts the bit pattern to the right - i.e. moves all the bits to the right - equivalent to dividing by a power of two
- `<<` shifts the bit patter to the left - i.e. moves all the bits to the left - equivalent to multiplying by a power of two :

5 >> 2 = 1 :
equivalent to

101 base 2 shifted right by 2 = 001 base 2 = 1

and

1 << 2  = 4 :
equivalent to

001 base 2 shifted left by 2 = 100 base 2 = 4