# How to access a function contained within a class in another module

Tags: python, python-2.7

This should be relatively simple, but I'm just missing something. I am trying to utilize a function from another module which is contained within a class. I can do it easily when there is no class involved.

```
# a.py
import b

b.name()
```

--

```
# b.py
def name():
    print "What is your name?"

class details(object):

    def age():
        print "What is your age?"
```

When I run a i get the expected result of

*What is your name?*

However when i try to access "def age()" from another module it keeps giving me trouble.

Some of what I have tried so far...

```
# c.py
import b

b.details.age()
```

= TypeError: unbound method age() must be called with details instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

```
# c.py
from b import details

details.age()
```

= TypeError: unbound method age() must be called with details instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

```
# c.py
from b import details

b.details(age)
```

= NameError: name 'b' is not defined

I have tried a few others as well but too many to reasonably post. What am i doing wrong? What is the syntax to do do this? Is it even possible to execute a function when it is contained within a class in another module?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** Fixed all tabs to spaces as suggested by Mike Graham

Comment: Your original posting was hard to follow because you had mixed spaces and tabs. Use all spaces with no hard tabs (and run python with the `-tt` option).

Comment: Thanks, ill try not to make that mistake in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of all class methods in Python is a reference to the current object (normally this is called self). However, that said, you seem to be trying to use it as a *static* method and not as an *instance* method, so perhaps you meant to use [the `@staticmethod` decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python):

```
class Details: # class names in Python should generally be CamelCased.
   # please note the comments below
   @staticmethod
   def age():
       print 'What is your age?'
```

Or, if you really want it to be an instance method, then you need to add `self` and change how you're referencing it:

```
class Details:
   def age(self):
       print 'What is your age?' 

# c.py
from b import Details
#you must create an instance of the class before you can call methods on it.
d = Details() 
d.age()
```

---

### EDIT

As noted in the comments, it is rare that `@staticmethod` has a genuine use case (it is often better to organize your code with modules, for example). You will often come across `@classmethod` as an alternative. Please note, though, that methods decorated with `@classmethod` have a reference to the current class as the first parameter. [This question addresses the major differences.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)

Comment: Your guess seems to be pretty off-the-wall here. Remember, *in the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess*.

Comment: @MikeGraham I don't see how it is off the wall, the OP's complaint matches that type of behavior rather directly.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Which version of Python is that? Because the example works on 2.7.2 for Windows.

Comment: weird you are right ... my apologies :) removed comment (and a +1)

Comment: @JoranBeasley, you're probably confusing the useful `classmethod` with `staticmethod`. (There is a general lack of usecases in well-designed code for using `staticmethod` as a decorator.)

Comment: Thanks for this, i did not know that i had to create an instance of the class to call it.