# Memoize a function which uses instance attributes

Tags: python, caching, memoization, python-decorators

I'm new to python and i couldn't find an answer online.
lets say i have a method which does some computation and returns a string

```
def output(self)
     a=self.some_long computation1()
     b=self.some_long computation2()
     c=self.some_attribute
     some_computatuion_inside
     return output_string
```

I'm using this function in a few places and want to memoize it, but since it takes no arguments and depends on instance attributes which can change between calls, im not sure how to proceed,

i realize i can write my own memoization function which will check if those attributes changed, but that seems incorrect, because that would be specific to this function only
and i would like maybe in the future to do the same for other functions

Comment: Try to consider ``some_long_computationX`` memoization

Answer (score 1):

One way is to pull out the variables (assuming they are hashable) and make it a [static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python):

```
@staticmethod
def output_static(a, b, c)
     some_computatuion_inside
     return output_string
```

And then call it from within the class as:

```
self.output_static(a=self.some_long_computation1()
                   b=self.some_long_computation2()
                   c=self.some_attribute)
```

*You could also use the techinque to memoize both `some_long_computation1` and `some_long_computation1`.*

If you wanted you could write an intermediary helper function which would simply call the (memomized) static method:

```
def output(self):
    return self.output_static(a=self.some_long_computation1()
                              b=self.some_long_computation2()
                              c=self.some_attribute)
```

Answer (score 1):

Decorators can compute the key based on any argument. Any instance method has an argument, that is `self`, and it's pretty easy to use to obtain a memoize decorator for methods:

```
CACHE = {}

def memoize(*attributes):
    def decorator(meth):
        def wrapper(self):
            key = tuple(getattr(self, attr) for attr in attributes)
            try:
                result = CACHE[key]
            except KeyError:
                result = CACHE[key] = meth(self)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Usage:

```
class Factorial(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    @memoize('n')
    def compute(self):
        if self.n in (0,1): return self.n
        else:
            return Factorial(self.n-1).compute() + Factorial(self.n-2).compute()


f = Factorial(100)

f.compute()
Out[4]: 354224848179261915075L
```