# Any ideas on why these two max/min value functions don't work for a BST in python?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

So, in the case of these two functions, I input something like:

```
 BSTTree.maxValue(BSTTree.root)
```

and let's say the BST looked something like this:

```
     6
    / \
   3   7
        \
         8
          \ 
           9
```

for max value it returns a "None" value. If i print out each root value, it will stop printing at 8... :/

Any ideas?

```
def maxValue(self, root):

    if (root.right is None):
        return root.value

    if (root.right is not None):

        self.maxVal(root.right)
        print root.value




def minValue(self, root):

     if (root.left is None):
        return root.value

     else:
         if (root.left is not None):
            self.minValue(root.left)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
self.maxVal(root.right)
```

should read

```
return self.maxVal(root.right)
```

Otherwise you're ignoring the return value from the recursive call.

The same goes for `minValue()`.

P.S. Since neither method needs `self`, you might want to consider turning them into [static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python).