# Access a function from a class in Python?

Tags: python, function, class, equation

I was wondering how would I access the "eq" function from my "formula" class? What I have tried does not work and returns "unbound method". Thanks.

```
class formula(): 
    def eq(): 
        print "What is your Velocity: " 
        v = float(raw_input()) 
        print "What is your Intial Velocity: " 
        u = float(raw_input())  
        print "What is the time: " 
        t = float(raw_input()) 
        aa = v-u 
        answer = aa/t 
        print "Your Acceleration is: ", answer 

a =formula.eq() 

print a
```

Comment: [static methods in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python)

Comment: Why is `eq` in `formula` at all? It looks like it belongs at module level.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give `eq` a `self` parameter, and create an *instance* of `formula` by calling it:

```
class formula(): 
    def eq(self): 
        print "What is your Velocity: " 
        v = float(raw_input()) 
        print "What is your Intial Velocity: " 
        u = float(raw_input())  
        print "What is the time: " 
        t = float(raw_input()) 
        aa = v-u 
        answer = aa/t 
        print "Your Acceleration is: ", answer 

formula().eq()
```

There is no point in storing the return value, you don't return anything here.

I note that you don't actually use anything in your function that *requires* a class. You could just as well leave the class out here and not lose anything

```
def eq(): 
    print "What is your Velocity: " 
    v = float(raw_input()) 
    print "What is your Intial Velocity: " 
    u = float(raw_input())  
    print "What is the time: " 
    t = float(raw_input()) 
    aa = v-u 
    answer = aa/t 
    print "Your Acceleration is: ", answer 

eq()
```

If you wanted to put your formula in a namespace, put it in a separate module instead; put `def eq()` in a file `formula.py` and import that as `import formula`. No point in making `eq()` a `staticmethod` here, really.

Answer (score 1):

make it like a static method

```
class formula(): 
    @staticmethod
    def eq():
        v = float(raw_input("What is your Velocity: ")) 
        u = float(raw_input("What is your Intial Velocity: "))  
        t = float(raw_input("What is the time: " )) 
        aa = v - u 
        answer = aa / t 
        print "Your Acceleration is: ", answer 
        return answer

a = formula.eq() 

print a
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
class formula(): 
def eq(self): 
    print "What is your Velocity: " 
    v = float(raw_input()) 
    print "What is your Intial Velocity: " 
    u = float(raw_input())  
    print "What is the time: " 
    t = float(raw_input()) 
    aa = v-u 
    answer = aa/t 
    print "Your Acceleration is: ", answer 

a = formula()
print a.eq()
```

Comment: touche. didn't catch it.

Comment: Your indentation is now off. Note that `formula().eq()` returns `None`; the `print` is pretty useless here.