# Is 'this' the cpp equivalent of 'self' in python?

Tags: python, c++, class, oop

I'm experienced in Python and now learning cpp to speed up code. After reading a bit `this` seems to be the cpp equivalent of `self`. I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526153/self-of-python-vs-this-of-cpp-c) explaining the difference from a cpp user's point of view but I'd like to know any differences for a python user's point of view.

Comment: `this` is a keyword in the c++ syntax and has special meaning. `self` is not a keyword in python, its just a common variable name people use when refering to their class instance for exmaple. but you are not forced to use the word `self` you could call it anything you want but convention says you "should" call it `self`

Comment: There are no more differences to the best of my knowledge. The differences are just technical - in `Python` you have to receive the parameter as an argument, and it is always the first one to the method. The naming convention is just that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of "this" keyword in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779645/use-of-this-keyword-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

The major difference is that you mostly don't need `this` in C++, because there is a syntactic distinction between defining a member and referring to it.

Contrast

Python:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar = 42

    def baz(self):
        return self._bar += 1
```

C++:

```
class Foo {
    int bar = 42;
public:
    int baz() { return bar += 1; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer already given, `self` in Python is just a conventional name chosen for the first argument of a class method which refers to the object itself that the method is called on directly.

In C++, `this` is a keyword that is not explicitly specified as a parameter of a non-static class member function, but automatically refers to the instance that such a function is called on as *pointer*.

That means `this` is not a reference to the object, but a pointer to it. So

```
this.member = 4;
```

is not possible. `this` must be dereferenced first to obtain a reference to the object from the pointer:

```
this->member = 4;
```

or (uncommonly)

```
(*this).member = 4;
```

With a few exceptions relating to name lookup in templates, the names of members refer to the current instances member automatically, as explained in the other answer, so `this->` can be dropped, usually:

```
member = 4;
```