# Python can i access a class method from another class without passing it as a parameter?

Tags: python, class, variables, methods, time

Experimenting with ex43.py (make a game) from LearnPythonTheHardWay and using `time.sleep()` to create pauses between events. In order to enable and disable the feature, or change the length of the pauses, I am just holding a variable in `class Engine()`, which is referenced from the calls to `time.sleep()` throughout the program.

So:

```
import time

class Engine(object):

    sleep1 = 1

    #some methods
    def say_hello(self, exit):
        self.exit = exit
        print "Hello"
        time.sleep(Engine.sleep1)
        self.exit.say_goodbye()

class Another(object):

    def say_goodbye(self):
        print "ok"
        time.sleep(Engine.sleep1)
        print "goodbye."

me = Engine()
bye = Another()
me.say_hello(bye)
```

The question is, if I want `time.sleep(1)` to be available to multiple methods of various classes, does it need to be passed to each method that needs it as a parameter like this:

```
import time

class Engine(object):

    sleep1 = 1

    #some methods
    def say_hello(self, exit):
        self.exit = exit
        print "Hello."
        time.sleep(Engine.sleep1)
        pause = time.sleep
        self.exit.say_goodbye(pause)

class Another(object):

    def say_goodbye(self, pause):
        self.pause = pause
        print "ok"
        self.pause(Engine.sleep1)
        print "goodbye."

me = Engine()
bye = Another()
me.say_hello(bye)
```

And in order to have just one place in which to set the length of the pause, is there an improvement on simple calling `time.sleep(Class.var)` from whatever method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen, I don't get the advantage of having `sleep1` inside a class, except if you want to change it during the game.

Passing `time.sleep(1)` around looks quite tedious. I would say that calling `time.sleep(Class.var)` every time is OK and makes the code clearer.

I also tested your code and passing the pause doesn't add any advantage to it:

- the code is harder to read
- you need to call it by doing this `self.pause(Engine.sleep1)` which is a strange alias for `time.sleep(Engine.sleep1)`. The one second is not remembered, so you have to input it again to `time.sleep()` **EDIT BELOW**
- you have more source lines of code which seem obscure, making it a lot harder to maintain

Keep it simple. `time.sleep(Engine.sleep1)` is good.

One small addition: if you only wait on specific functions, calling `time.sleep()` is perfectly fine. But if you're doing this after each function, maybe you could do some kind of "action queue" and call `time.sleep()` after each function has completed. So that if your logic changes, you can update one single line of code.

**EDIT**: To keep the function and it's parameters for `time.sleep()`, I would do the following:

```
MY_SLEEP = 1

def my_pause():
    time.sleep(MY_SLEEP)

my_pause() # waits 1 second
my_pause() # waits 1 second again.
```

but then again, you could simply:

```
time.sleep(MY_SLEEP)
```

each time...

**EDIT 2**
Here I somewhat combined the idea with the static method and the printing into a `say()`function.

```
import time

MY_SLEEP = 1 # inside a config file

class Engine(object):

    @staticmethod
    def say(text):
        print(text)
        time.sleep(MY_SLEEP)

    #some methods
    def say_hello(self, exit):
        Engine.say("Hello")
        exit.say_goodbye()

class Another(object):

    def say_goodbye(self):
        Engine.say("ok")
        Engine.say("goodbye")

me = Engine()
bye = Another()
me.say_hello(bye)
```

When I was talking about an action queue, it was more like a list containing which class/function/arg to call at each round. Then a loop would `pop` one element from the queue at each turn, do the action, wait one second and start again.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about just creating SLEEP1 outside of a class to make it globally accessible (and naming with CAPS). But the question is really, Does a method have to be passed as a parameter to be available within another classes method? And secondly is there any way to attach a method AND it's parameter together for example `var = time.sleep(1)` (which i know won't work because it just references the return value of the function)

Comment: If it's an instance method, you'll have to pass it as a parameter to be available within another class I think. If it's a `@staticmethod`, you can call it without passing it as a parameter ( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python )

Comment: About your second question, the way I would do it is define a function called `my_sleep()` in which I have `time.sleep(1)`. So everytime I call my function, it sleeps for 1 second. See edit above (in answer)

Comment: I like the `my_pause()` as a static method - since this is an `OOP` exercise. `    @staticmethod
    def my_pause():
        time.sleep(Engine.sleep1)` Would you be up for adding that to your answer before I accept it? Mostly what I'm using it for is just to delay time between sentences being printed out. Would a function that would accept a paragraph string and insert `time.sleep` based on `\n` or number of words be kind of what you're talking about with an "action queue"?

Answer (score 1):

An approach that I use is to create a module with all constants and simple helper methods that might be needed by other modules, classes and their methods, so it's not even a class, e.g. a helper.py module can look like this:

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
def method1():
    ...
def method2():
    ...
```

I would put that helper.py to a library, say mylib, and then use it from other modules, classes and executable like this:

```
from mylib import helper
print helper.var1
helper.method1()
helper.method2()
```

Needless to say that I don't need to instantiate anything with this approach.

Comment: Cool. That's pretty simple. Or I could simply put the function outside of a class and either way it can easily be called from within a method. Awesome. This stuff really isn't all that complicated, is it? Maybe someday I'll even understand threads...