# Python 2.7 - DocTest fails if I try to create static method inside a class

Tags: python, class, methods, static

I am having problems with a class called `LatencyList`.

The complete code can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/b5bemMsW

In this Class I have 2 method that dont need to reference to the object (self) but I can't remove the "self" parameter without making fail the DocTest:

```
def crop_latencies(self, lat_list):
    """
    Return "lat_list" with only latencies (exclude all None(s) that mean PacketLoss)
    """
    cropped_list = []
    for latency in lat_list:
        if latency is not None:
            cropped_list.append(latency)
    return cropped_list

def count_packetlost(self, lat_list):
    """
    Return None(packetloss) counts in "lat_list"
    """
    counter = 0
    for latency in lat_list:
        if latency is None:
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

Here the errors during DocTest if i try to remove the "self" parameter: http://pastebin.com/mm8YgRSM

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are these functions inside a class somewhere else in your code?
Edit: they are.

Comment: Errors added; yes, these function are used by others non static functions

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@staticmethod` in front of your function declaration.

```
class A:
    def a_method(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def a_static_method():
        pass
```

Visit [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python) for more.