# Static method seems to be getting passed 'self'nonetheless

Tags: python, static-methods

I have defined a class with a static method. But when I call it, it produces an error saying that two args are being passed when only one is required. I have defined other static methods in other classes, and called them the same way, and they have worked fine. I can perhaps post source code tomorrow, but for now, I only have Internet access from my phone, which does not have the source code.

Is there some common error that produces the sort of thing I am seeing?

Comment: What is the language? Anyway, if you have no source code, you should have waited to post until you did, otherwise your question will likely be closed.

Comment: Sorry, I was dictating my question: "I have to find" should have read "I have defined"

Comment: Sorry, python. I am trying to work this problem out now on the computer with no Internet access, and just trying to see if there is a common cause of this sort of thing. I sincerely wish I could post source code at this moment, but the computer with the code has no Internet access at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're calling the method with

```
ClassName.Method();
```

and not

```
ClassInstance.Method();
```

?

Comment: Yes, coding orange, i am calling it the same way I am calling all my other static class instances. In this case, self.props = pa.PropArgs.get_props(prog_nm) where pa is a package andPropArgs a class in that package

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python) It looks like you may not be defining it quite right. It is a rather icky syntax. And you're sure you're using the same python version as before?

Comment: Yes, clearly I am doing something subtle wrong. But all this code is running in Python 3.4. And my other class method definitions work fine in 3.4. So what I am asking is, has anyone else encountered this type of error, and what is the settled thing I am doing wrong?

Comment: I will type in by hand the method definition:

Comment: @classmethod (nl) def get_props(prog_nm): some code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner?rq=1

important excerpt: Though classmethod and staticmethod are quite similar, there's a slight difference in usage for both entities: classmethod must have a reference to a class object as the first parameter, whereas staticmethod can have no parameters at all.

Comment: Thanks, codingorange: I tried redefining the method as a static method, but I get the exact same result.

Comment: Here is the line blowing up: self.props = pa.PropArgs.get_props("nm")

Comment: pa is a package name. PropArgs is aclass in that pkg. get_props is defined as a class method in that class. My cold seems identical to numerous other instances of me doing this that work. I understand that I have made a mistake somewhere: I just want to know if anyone has seen this sort of mistake before?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can tell what your problem is. I do hope you figure it out though!

Comment: Sorry for all the weird words above: I am dictating my comments from my phone.

Comment: Ok, so I simply hard-coded the value of PROG_NM in the line self.props = pa.PropArgs.get_props("fashion.py")

Comment: Now i get 'PropArgs' object has no attribute 'PropArgs' here, I think, is the key to my error: what does this mean?

Comment: I just tried eliminating import prop_args as pa and using the whole module name instead. This made my error revert back to the previous one: the wrong number of positional arguments. What is going on here? Changing between a module name and an "as" module name gives different error messages?

Comment: Aargh: now i just eliminated the pkg name before the static method name, and the code works fine! But i have no idea what the difference is!

Comment: Ok, The code now seems to be working fine, but I still have no idea what I originally did wrong, or why the various tweaks I performed produced different error messages.

Comment: And I am no coding newbie: I have programmed in C, C++, Pascal, object Pascal, lisp, awk, Perl, Java, and another half a dozen languages I have probably forgotten. But what I just went through in getting this code to work is really bizarre to me.