# Unable to use function from another python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following script in a python file *classfile.py*

```
class Myclass:
    def testadd(x,y):
           return x+y
```

In another python file callfile.py

```
from classfile import Myclass
print testadd(3, 5)
```

while running the script `callfile.py`, I am getting

> NameError: name 'testadd' is not defined

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: It's not a function, it's a method: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: @Ashwini How can I call that method from another without creating an object?

Comment: @PrabhakarD You can make it a static method, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/735978/4374739) explains how to do that. You'll still need to call it as `module.class.method_name` but it can do what you want.

Comment: Why do you want `testadd(x,y)` to be in a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define the method as a "classmethod":

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class Myclass():
   @classmethod
   def testadd(cls, x, y):
       return x + y
```

Then you can use it in this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from classfile import Myclass

print Myclass.testadd(3, 5)
```

without using the "classmethod" decorator you can only use it in this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from classfile import Myclass

aclass = Myclass()
print aclass.testadd(4, 5)
```

Comment: yep. static method is more appropriate in this case!

Comment: see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)

Comment: Thanks @Marvix. Your answer helps me a lot..!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this.

## classfile.py

```
class MyClass:
    def testadd(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y 
        return x+y
```

## callfile.py

```
import classfile
ob = classfile.MyClass()
print ob.testadd(21,3)
```