# TypeError for Unbound Method in Python Class and Factory Method

Tags: python, class

So, I have a class, where a class variable is set to the output from a class factory in the `__init__` method, like so:

```
def MyFooFactory():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # Do __init__ stuff

    def MyBar(myFoo_obj):
        print "MyBar"

    newclass = type("MyFoo", tuple(object), {"__init__": __init__, "MyBar": MyBar} )
    return newclass

class Foo:
    Bar = 0
    def __init__(self):
        if (type(Foo.Bar) is int):
            Bar = MyFooFactory()

    def MyBar(a_list):
        for l in a_list:
            Bar.MyBar(l)
```

However, when I try this

```
myBar_list = [Foo.Bar() for _ in range(x)]
Foo.MyBar(myBar_list)
```

TypeError: unbound method MyBar() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got list instead)

Is this happening because `MyBar` has the same name in both `Foo` and `MyFoo` or is there something else afoot here?

For reference, both `MyBar` methods are supposed to be unbound.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance methods in Python *must* have `self` as first argument (where `self` is really just a formal parameter name like any other - it gets bound to the instance by virtue of being the first one), so you'd have

```
def MyBar(self, a_list):
    ...
```

On the other hand, if you did want a *static* method you'd have to [use the `@staticmethod` decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/735978/3881403):

```
@staticmethod
def MyBar(a_list):
    ...
```

See also this answer: [What is the difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)

Comment: So, would this work if I wrote `Foo.Bar = MyFooFactory()` then?

Comment: You can do that *inside* the class definition (see my comment under @6502's answer).

Answer (score 2):

It's because you forgot `self` parameter in `MyBar`

Try this:

```
class Foo:
    ...

    def MyBar(self, a_list):
        for l in a_list:
            Bar.MyBar(l)
```

If it's supposed to be "unbound" method use `@staticmethod` [decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod):

Comment: I didn't forget it, it's supposed to be an unbound method.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
Bar = MyFooFactory()
```

is assigning a local, not the class-level `Bar` member that is called in `Foo.MyBar`

If you want to assign that inside a method the syntax is

```
Foo.Bar = MyFooFactory()
```

Scope rules inside the class body are somewhat surprising.

Comment: I see! So that's what I was doing wrong. So how would I assign the class-level `Bar`?

Comment: `class Foo: \n
    Bar = MyFooFactory` (*outside* the `__init__` method) should do what you want.