# why does Python treat data attrs and function attrs at the "same level" differently?

Tags: python, class, attributes

Given this class:

```
class Person:
  lastName = ""
  firstName = ""

  def getFullName(self, lastName, firstName):
    self.instanceLevel_lastName = lastName
    self.instanceLevel_firstName = firstName
```

Why does Python choose to treat `firstName` and `lastName` as class-level attrs, and `getFullName()` as an instance-level member/method, although they are defined at the "same level"? I'd thought by default, the same-level attrs would be treated in the "same way" which should ALL be instance-level members.

I realize this is not a programming question, but it's more about the language design. I come from C++ background, so I'm a bit puzzled about this behavior in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self):
      self.firstName = ""
      self.lastName = ""

  def getFullName(self):
    ...
```

Will give you instance-level attributes.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to ask "how to" define instance-level variables. I've edited my question.

Comment: Oh sorry. Yeah, I guess it is a little counterintuitive that variables defined in a class are shared between all instances without the self modifer, without having to be marked with any particular modifier themselves, but I believe it follows from the way Python namespaces work, which seems to be driven by modules more than classes. It's very obvious from that perspective why a variable defined at module level is global to the module without further encapsulation. It's definitely different than most other languages where a source file name doesn't have much significance.

Answer (score 0):

To get static methods you need to use the @staticmethod decorator.

```
class MyClass:
    classAttr = 4

    @staticmethod
    def static_foo():
        print("Static Shock!")
```

This is done most likely because there is seldom a need for static methods in python, as they can often be replaced by top-level functions in the module.

See this question for more info: [Static methods in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python)

Comment: I think by the same token, "static" variables are not of typical use either, and therefore, why are they not treated as instance-level member instead?

Comment: @Ltf4an I don't know. I do know that one can define instance variables in places other than the __init__ function, though it's generally frowned upon. All instance variables have the self.varName convention, whereas the class variables are defined under the class name. I think it just comes down to readability at that point, from my experience new programmers find the self.varName a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not, in fact, treat `getFullName` as an instance-level member differently from `lastName` and `firstName` in your example.  All of these are defined at the class-level an can be accessed as such.

If I change your example slightly:

```
class Person:
  lastName = ""
  firstName = ""

  def getFullName(self):
    return("{} {}".format(self.firstName, self.lastName))
```

Note that you can access all of these via the class:

```
>>> Person.firstName
''
>>> Person.getFullName
<function Person.getFullName at 0x104168c80>
```

And you can access all of these via an instance:

```
>>> p = Person()
>>> p.firstName
''
>>> p.getFullName
<bound method Person.getFullName of <__main__.Person object at 0x104173240>>
```

That is, they are all class attributes, and you can access any class attribute via an instance.

Now, you can see here that how you access the method `getFullName` does affect what you get, in that `Person.getFullName` is a function (that takes `self` as it's first argument) and `p.getFullName` is a bound method (in which self is already bound, so it doesn't take that argument):

```
>>> p = Person()
>>> Person.getFullName(p)
' '
>>> p.getFullName()
' '
```

Similarly, `Person.firstName = "Bob"` will set the class attribute `firstName`, whereas `p.firstName = "Bob"` will set the instance attribute `firstName`, and the instance variable will shadow the class variable next time you access `p.firstName`:

```
>>> Person.firstName = "Bob"
>>> p.firtName
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'firtName'
>>> Person.firstName = "Bob"
>>> p.firstName 
'Bob'
>>> p.firstName = "Joe"
>>> p.firstName
'Joe'
>>> Person.firstName
'Bob'
```