# Why Python 3.X allows self argument in class's method to be other than an instance type, meanwhile Python 2.x doesn't?

Tags: python

Given the example:

```
>>> class Cool: 
...    def mthd(self, val): 
...        self.val = val 
...

>>> def x(): pass

>>> Cool.mthd(x, 360)      # Works in 3.X only, not in 2.X
```

2.X raises `**TypeError: unbound method...**` error, but in 3.x it works just fine.

> Why does Python 2.X restricts **self** argument to be only an instance type, whereas Python 3.X doesn't restrict it to any data type? 
>   And why was this changed in 3.X?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static methods in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know *why* it was changed (I *guess* to remove a concept that didn't add a lot of value), but the change is documented [in the 'What’s New In Python 3.0' documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods):

> The concept of “unbound methods” has been removed from the language. When referencing a method as a class attribute, you now get a plain function object.

With this change,

```
my_cool.mthd(360)
```

just becomes a (very recommended!) short hand notation for

```
type(my_cool).mthd(my_cool, 360)
```

Comment: I don't _know_ the reason either, but the change allows one to use classes as simple namespaces which are supposedly "one honking great idea" according to [PEP 10 - The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: Also, "Simple is better than complex." And not having the concept of “unbound methods” is clearly simpler than having it. Also, less complicated. Could also be a case of "[P]racticality beats purity."

Comment: Perhaps the idea is to make dual usages for classes' methods, one as a methods mode and the other as simple functions.