# Best practice to implement multiple constructors in python

Tags: python, math, line

I'm pretty sure this has been asked many times but I'm still not sure how to implement the multiple constructors in Python. I know that in python, I can only have one constructor unlike in java or C# or C++. I'm still pretty new to it. Long story short, I need to implement a line object. The line will be represented by the function y = ax + b. So the only things I need to store in the line are a, b and a boolean for the special case where the line is vertical (a = infinity). In that case, a will store the x position of the line. To create a line, I have 3 ways. 1 is to directly put in a, b and the boolean. 2 is to put in 2 points in form of tuples. 3 is to put in a point and a vector. My code so far:

```
class line:
    def __init__(self, a, b, noSlope):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.noSlope = noSlope

    def lineFromPoints(point1, point2):
        deltaX = point2[0] - point1[0]
        deltaY = point2[1] - point1[1]
        if deltaX == 0:
            return line(point1[0], 0, True)
        else:
            a = deltaY / deltaX
            b = point1[1] - a * point1[0]
            return line(a, b, False)

    def lineFromVector(vector, point):
        if vector[0] == 0:
            return line(point1[0], 0, True)
        else:
            a = vector[1] / vector[0]
            b = point1[1] - a * point1[0]
            return line(a, b, False)
```

Not sure if there's a better way to do this

Comment: As this is a python question, please remove the c# and c++ tags as it has nothing to do with your problem

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for specifically, and the constructor looks fine as is, but a couple of things that stand out - class names are always capitalized, so call it `class Line:`. Also for all those index lookups,  (`point1[0]` etc.), you could say `x1, y1 = point1` and `x2, y2 = point2` and then your `deltaX` could just be `x2-x1` and later you could reuse `x1, x2, y1, y2`, etc. Basically think of your notation as how would I do this if I were trying to solve some similar math equation on paper.

Comment: "Better ways" yes, your code doesn't even work. Make `lineFromPoints()` and `lineFromVector()` static methods or just take them outside the class and that's all.

Comment: @BAH can you explain what exactly `x1, y1 = point1` does? That might be very useful for this algorithm

Comment: @JackLe I'm assuming your `point1` is a tuple that contains two elements, say `(0, 1)`. `x1, y1 = point1` unpacks that tuple and gives you two variables, `x1 = 0, y1 = 1`, and, from that point on, you can just start using those variables instead of saying `point1[0], point1[1]` etc.

Comment: @BAH thanks. I never knew of that. Python is wonderful!

Comment: @JackLe See my edit for an additional way to implement the constructors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The more pythonic way of doing multiple constructors is with [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#classmethod), as suggested by [Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4952130/jim). Raymond Hettinger did a talk on Python's class development toolkit at Pycon 2013, where he talked about [multiple constructors](https://youtu.be/HTLu2DFOdTg?t=27m42s) using `@classmethod`.

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, a, b, noSlope):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.noSlope = noSlope

    @classmethod
    def fromPoints(cls, point1, point2):
        deltaX = point2[0] - point1[0]
        deltaY = point2[1] - point1[1]
        if deltaX == 0:
            return cls(point1[0], 0, True)
        else:
            a = deltaY / deltaX
            b = point1[1] - a * point1[0]
            return cls(a, b, False)

    @classmethod
    def fromVector(cls, vector, point):
        if vector[0] == 0:
            return cls(point1[0], 0, True)
        else:
            a = vector[1] / vector[0]
            b = point1[1] - a * point1[0]
            return cls(a, b, False)


line = Line.fromPoints((0,0), (1,1))
```

Similar to `self`, the `cls` parameter for the `@classmethod` functions is implicitly passed as the calling class (in the example above, it would be `Line`). This is used to accommodate future subclasses using the additional constructors; it removes potential bugs from accidentally bypassing a subclass's implementation of a constructor by hard coding the base class in place of `cls`.

---

**ORIGINAL POST:**

If you want to enforce the use of your constructors, you can make them [static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python), and have them return an instance of your class.

```
class line:
    def __init__(self, a, b, noSlope):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.noSlope = noSlope

    @staticmethod
    def lineFromPoints(point1, point2):
        deltaX = point2[0] - point1[0]
        deltaY = point2[1] - point1[1]
        if deltaX == 0:
            return line(point1[0], 0, True)
        else:
            a = deltaY / deltaX
            b = point1[1] - a * point1[0]
            return line(a, b, False)

    @staticmethod
    def lineFromVector(vector, point):
        if vector[0] == 0:
            return line(point1[0], 0, True)
        else:
            a = vector[1] / vector[0]
            b = point1[1] - a * point1[0]
            return line(a, b, False)

# Create instance of class
myLine = line.lineFromPoints((0,0), (1,1))
```

EDIT:
If you want to force use of your constructors over the use of `Line.__init__`, you can use the following factory to hide direct instantiation of the Line class:

```
class LineFactory:
    class Line:
        def __init__(self, a, b, noSlope):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
            self.noSlope = noSlope

    @staticmethod
    def fromPoints(point1, point2):
        deltaX = point2[0] - point1[0]
        deltaY = point2[1] - point1[1]
        if deltaX == 0:
            return LineFactory.Line(point1[0], 0, True)
        else:
            a = deltaY / deltaX
            b = point1[1] - a * point1[0]
            return LineFactory.Line(a, b, False)

    @staticmethod
    def fromVector(vector, point):
        if vector[0] == 0:
            return LineFactory.Line(point1[0], 0, True)
        else:
            a = vector[1] / vector[0]
            b = point1[1] - a * point1[0]
            return LineFactory.Line(a, b, False)

# Create line    
line = LineFactory.fromPoints((0,0), (1,1))
```

Comment: I was about to edit my comment and suggest static methods, this is a good approach. You could also capitalize the class name (just a suggestion)

Comment: I would suggest capitalizing the name as well!

Comment: Question: can I still use the Line class now that it's enclosed inside of LineFactory class?

Comment: Absolutely. The factory methods will return an instance of the Line class that you can use just like any other instance. I added clarification in my example so you can see `LineFactory.*` returns a line.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help.

Comment: `classmethod` is more suitable for alternate constructors, really, and that's what you suggest in your approaches. That's how many of the standard library classes provide it too.

Comment: @Jim I have updated my post. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

You could create one constructor with all required parameters with default value None:

```
class line:
    def __init__(self, a = None, b = None, noSlope = None, point1 = None, point2 = None, vector = None, point = None):
        pass
```

Then you will check which paameters are passed in constructor and create line from these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pyhton's enums to declare the initialization method as follows:

```
from enum import Enum

class Line:

    class InitTypes(Enum):
        coefs, point_vector, point_point, vertical = range(4)


    def __init__(self, a, b, method):
        self.noSlope = False
        if method == Line.InitTypes.coefs:
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
        elif method == Line.InitTypes.point_vector:
            # Do math
            pass
        elif method == Line.InitTypes.point_point:
            # Do math
            pass
        elif method == Line.InitTypes.vertical:
            self.noSlope = True
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
        else:
            assert(False)
```

Then, create a line as follows:

```
x = Line((0,1), (3,4), Line.InitTypes.point_point)
```