# Name is not defined in Python

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm using Python 2.7.12 and trying this code.

```
clientNet = []
class Client:
    def __init__(self, host, user, password):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.session = self.connect()
    def connect(self):
        try:
            s = pxssh.pxssh()
            s.login(self.host, self.user, self.password)
            return s
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            print '[-] Error Connecting'
    def botnetCommand(command):
        for client in clientNet:
            output = client.send_command(command)
            print '[*] Output from ' + client.host
            print '[+] ' + output + '\n'
    def send_command(self, cmd):
        self.session.sendline(cmd)
        self.session.prompt()
        return self.session.before
    def addClient(host, user, password):
        client = Client(host, user, password)
        clientNet.append(client)

addClient('192.168.1.94','root','root')
```

And

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "host.py", line 33, in <module>
    addClient('192.168.1.94','root','root')
NameError: name 'addClient' is not defined
```

I tried to run `Client.addClient(..)` but didn't resolve my problem. 
I think I need some help to understand this.. How cannot be defined if it is inside of the Class?

Comment: You need to create an instance of `Client` first... `myClient = Client('192.168.1.94','root','root')`

Comment: In addition to all other answers, you need to add `self` to `addClient`'s arguments (and probably also to the other methods as well)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an instance of the class to use its methods first:

```
client = Client('192.168.1.94','root','root')
client.addClient('192.168.1.95','root','root')
```

Otherwise you could use a **static method** if you define the method as:

```
...
@staticmethod
def addClient(host, user, password):
    client = Client(host, user, password)
    clientNet.append(client)
```

and use it like:

```
Client.addClient(...)
```

without having to make an instance.

Comment: This will still not work.  `addClient` is an instance method but it doesn't reserve an argument for the instance.

Comment: I am fully aware it won't fully work. However I answered his question and I have no need to solve his task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i don't understand why if I turn the method static I can use just add cliente and otherwise no