# Django - missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django, web, django-rest-framework

I'm getting the error

> get_indiceComercioVarejista() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'request'

when trying to access the method get_indiceComercioVarejista. I don't know what it's wrong with it.

views:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import requests
import pandas as pd

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ChartData(APIView):

    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):

         data = {
            'customer' : 10,
            'sales': 100
        }

        return Response(data)

    def get_indiceComercioVarejista(self, request, format=None):
        data = {
            'customer' : 10,
            'sales': 100
        }
        return Response(data)
```

urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'Oraculum_Data/login.html'}),
    url(r'^cancerColo/$', views.cancerColo),
    url(r'^educacao/$', views.educacao),
    url(r'^comercio/$', views.comercio),
    url(r'^saude/$', views.saude),
    url(r'^api/chart/data/$', views.ChartData.as_view()),
    url(r'^api/chart/indiceVolumeReceitaComercioVarejista/$', views.ChartData.get_indiceComercioVarejista)
]
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: You want `.get` to do that and use `views.ChartData.as_view()` in your urls... (or have the prepare/dispatch method for the apiview pick the appropriate get method if you've got more than one depending on whatever criteria...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`request` is passed as a first argument. Your first argument is `self`.

This is why it would be a good idea to extract `get_indiceComercioVarejista` from `ChartData` class:

```
def get_indiceComercioVarejista(request, format=None):
    data = {
        'customer' : 10,
        'sales': 100
    }
    return Response(data)
```

Comment: still not working. The get method is passing self as the first argument and it works fine.

Comment: Did you extract `get_indiceComercioVarejista` method from the class? `get` method will work because you're using it via `as_view()`,

Answer (score 3):

I think the best approach would be to move `get_indiceComercioVarejista` out of the APIView, because `APIView` just dispatchs to the regular http methods: `get post put patch delete`.

e.g:

**view.py**

```
def get_indiceComercioVarejista(request, format=None):
    data = {
        'customer' : 10,
        'sales': 100
    }
    return Response(data)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^api/chart/indiceVolumeReceitaComercioVarejista/$', views.get_indiceComercioVarejista)
```

Another solution would be to use [ViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) which are the recommended when working with DRF.

Comment: Didn't work. Error: TypeError: as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the other answers:

Your view defines `get_iniceComercioVarejista` as an instance method of the `ChartData` class.

However, in your urls.py, you have the following line:

```
url(r'^api/chart/indiceVolumeReceitaComercioVarejista/$', views.ChartData.get_indiceComercioVarejista)
```

You must declare an instance of `ChartData` by adding parentheses for that line to work as your view code is currently written. The modified line should read:

```
url(r'^api/chart/indiceVolumeReceitaComercioVarejista/$', views.ChartData().get_indiceComercioVarejista)
```

An alternative solution is removing `self` from the method definition as others have suggested, i.e.:

```
def get_indiceComercioVarejista(request, format=None)
```

This approach implicitly turns `get_indiceComercioVarejista` into a static method (read the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python)) and your urls.py would work as written. If you choose this solution, I strongly suggest adding a `staticmethod` decorator.

Finally, if you decide to move `get_indiceComercioVarejista` out of the `ChartData` class, then remove the `self` argument and use the solution from @Willemoes

Answer (score 0):

just remove self

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import requests
import pandas as pd

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ChartData(APIView):

    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):

         data = {
            'customer' : 10,
            'sales': 100
        }

        return Response(data)


#just remove self from bellow function it's unnecessary

#before
    def get_indiceComercioVarejista(self, request, format=None):
        data = {
            'customer' : 10,
            'sales': 100
        }
        return Response(data)
      
#after
    def get_indiceComercioVarejista(request, format=None):
        data = {
            'customer' : 10,
            'sales': 100
        }
        return Response(data)
```