# How to pass self and 2 arguments to thread

Tags: python, multithreading, parameter-passing

I'm simply trying to pass `self` and 2 other arguments to a thread, but I'm getting an error every time.

I tried following other samples, but nothing has worked so far.

```
class X:
    def start(self):
        newStartupThread = threading.Thread(target=self.launch, args=(t1_stop, 
            self.launchAdditionalParams))
        newStartupThread.name = "ClientLaunchThread%d" % 
            (self.launchAttemptCount+1)
        newStartupThread.daemon = True
        newStartupThread.start()


    def launch(self, test, additionalParams):
        pass
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: launch() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

**Edited the code to show that it is in a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the presence of `self`, I assume this is in a class.

```
import threading


class X:
    def start(self):
        t1_stop = 8
        self.launchAdditionalParams = {}

        newStartupThread = threading.Thread(
            target=self.launch,
            args=(t1_stop, self.launchAdditionalParams),
        )
        newStartupThread.name = "ClientLaunchThread"
        newStartupThread.daemon = True
        newStartupThread.start()

    def launch(self, test, additionalParams):
        print(locals())


x = X()
x.start()
```

works fine for me, outputting

```
{'additionalParams': {}, 'test': 8, 'self': <__main__.X object at 0x000001442938F438>}
```

Comment: I did forget to show that its in a class. I edited the code to show the same. Using the lambda, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Oofp, I had actually forgotten the lambda from my example anyway. Anyway, I can't reproduce your original problem; see edit.

Comment: OK thanks, super odd that it doesn't work on my system. At least I now know Im not crazy.

Answer (score 0):

`launch` is a function, not a method. Only methods need the `self` argument. Just remove the self argument and it should work:

```
def launch(test, additionalParams):
```

If it is within a class, you have to do one of two things:

- Call it *only* on instances of the class (`someClass.launch(arg1, arg2)`)
- Make it a [static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python) by not including the `self` argument