# whats difference @instance and @static method in python?

Tags: python

I have 2 different code but they both work why?

```
class Calculator:
    def multiplyNums(x, y):
        return x + y
print('Product:', Calculator.multiplyNums(15, 110))
```

and

```
class Calculator:
    @staticmethod
    def multiplyNums(x, y):
        return x + y
print('Product:', Calculator.multiplyNums(15, 110))
```

what does @staticmethod?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod

Comment: Create an instance of your first `Calculator` class and  try to use the function through that instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static methods in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what is the effect of the `@staticmethod` decorator by doing:

```
cc = Calculator()
print(cc.multiplyNums(10, 2))
```

Without `@staticmethod`, the above code gives you an error:

> TypeError: multiplyNums() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

because you are implicitly passing `cc` as argument to the method (the `self` argument that you usually see as the first argument in method definitions, which in this case is not present).

With the `@staticmethod` decorator, it works, and prints `12`.

Basically the decorator allows you to call methods without the `self` argument from class instances.

Answer (score -2):

I have just edited your 1st method to make it instance method

```
 class Calculator:
 def multiplyNums(self,x, y):
    return x + y
 print('Product:', Calculator().multiplyNums(15, 110))

class Calculator:
@staticmethod
def multiplyNums(x, y):
    return x + y
print('Product:', Calculator.multiplyNums(15, 110))
```

So static method can neither modify object state nor class state. Static methods are restricted in what data they can access - and they’re primarily a way to namespace your methods.

Comment: Hello! While the link may provide an anwers, link-only solution are discouraged. Please add some details in the question.

Comment: What's difference between this two codes, other than that the results are same and what does @staticmode do?