# How to use method without instance initialization?

Tags: python, class, initialization, static-methods, class-method

Currently I am doing this to use `SampleClass.method1()`:

```
output = SampleClass().method1(input_var)
```

But instead, I want to do this:

```
output = SampleClass.method1(input_var).
```

How do I do this?

```
class SampleClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 'var1'
        self.var2 = 'var2'

    def method1(self, input_var):
        self.var3 = self._method2(input_var)
        return self._method3(self.var3)

    def _method2(self):
        pass

    def _method3(self):
        pass
```

Is it feasible to change the above class to the following?

```
class SampleClass(object):

    def __init__(self, input_var):
        self.var1 = 'var1'
        self.var2 = 'var2'
        return self.method1(input_var)

    def method1(self, input_var):
        self.var3 = self._method2(input_var)
        return self._method3(self.var3)

    def _method2(self):
        pass

    def _method3(self):
        pass
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can write a class method, but `method1` is accessing instance variables, so it only makes sense as an instance method.

Comment: `method1()` uses the instance `self` in the method. What do you want that to be?

Comment: Can you give me some example code? The class structure can change, I just want to write a class that uses a method where it doesn't have to do this: SampleClass().method1(input_var) to call the method, but instead does this: SampleClass.method1(input_var). Thanks.

Comment: See e.g. [Static methods in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a static method. And yes, you can write one in Python. A good example with explanation has been already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python).