# Returning different number and types of values?

Tags: python, design-patterns, return

Often I need to have function OR method return different number OR types of values.
For example :

```
def test(x,y,ret='both') :
  s = x + y
  m = x * y
  if ret = 'both' : return s, m
  if ret = 'sum' : return s
  if ret = 'mult' : return m
```

Also sometimes I want to have Aspect type behavior where I inject debugging code, which may also change the return types/num-of-vals

Is there a standard Programming pattern that handle this ? Decorators ?

The example work but is abit clunky..

---

this is just example ... for illustration, dont take it as canonical approach

Comment: a `staticmethod` may be the best approach to go about this, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python)

Comment: So, Python functions can only ever return a single value. That value may be a *container* like a `tuple` in your case. But it's only a single value. In general, I would say a function having multiple different return types is an anti-pattern, and there is no standard way to handle it.

Comment: @FishingCode how is that at all relevant? This is a function, not a method.

Comment: why would a `tuple` be useful if OP is going to inject code? `tuple` is immutable...

Comment: @sten Did you find any other approach for this?

Comment: @alan.elkin not yet ... ;(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is convenient that any atomic action is performed by a different function.
Anyways, if you still want to perform several calculations in the same function and you don't mind about performance, you could always return both sum and mult (and any other variable), and leave to the caller the task of selecting what is needed. Personally, I find dictinaries a nice approach:

```
def test(x, y) :
    values = {}
    values['sum'] = x + y
    values['mult'] = x * y
    return values
```

Comment: what about the condition for 'both' i.e. returning sum and mult

Comment: They are in the dict already. You can access both values['sum'] and values['mult'] from the caller side

Comment: ah ok, in that sense it is since it would be {'sum': ..., 'mult':...}.