# I want to generate random numbers with this code but it generates error

Tags: python, class, tuples

With this code I want to generate a tuple of random numbers. I know that there are easy ways to do it without using classes but I want the code to have class too.

```
import random

class Dice:
    def roll(self):
        generate = random.randint(1, 6)
        generate2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        return generate, generate2

dice = Dice
print(dice.roll())
```

It generates this error:

```
print(dice.roll()) 
TypeError: roll() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

and when I change my code like this : print(dice.roll(self))
it creates another error that the self name is not defined.

Comment: Try looking at this answer for static class methods.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python
The issue is that the roll() method expects self, using a static method removes this expectation.

Answer (score 5):

```
import random

class Dice:
    def roll(self):
        generate = random.randint(1, 6)
        generate2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        return generate, generate2

dice = Dice() <----you omitted this
print(dice.roll())
```