# How to define a function where it doesn't matter whether you call the class

Tags: python, function, class, call

I am writing a program similar to the short program below:

```py
class Class():
 def __init__(self):
  pass
 def foo():
  pass
```

Whenever I call `foo` as `Class.foo()` everything inside `foo` works fine.

*However*, when I call it as `Class().foo()`, then I get an error: by calling `Class` I give `foo` an extra argument, `self.`
If I added the argument `self` to `foo`, then it won't work if I call the function as `Class.foo()`.

How can I avoid this? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Which programming language is that? Please add an appropriate tag. Also, if you know that you can call that method the one way, but not the other, why not simply use the working way?

Comment: @NicoHaase its python sorry i added the tag

Comment: Seems to be related: [Static methods in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/735975/45183410)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `foo` should be a [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod).

```
class Class:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        pass

print(Class.foo())  # -> None
print(Class().foo())  # -> None
```

*P.S. I can expand on this if needed. The question is a bit vague.*

Comment: thanks! I didn't expect there would be a decorator for this... :)