# How to call a function defined in a class, outside of its class it is defined in?

Tags: python

I made a function `drive_car` inside of the class `car`, but I do not know how to call it from the class it is defined in, outside of the class, while staying inside of its class.

```
class car:
      def drive_car():
          print("car go vroom vroom")
car.drive_car() # -- gives error message
```

Comment: This is covered in any tutorial on classes.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  You seem to have skipped the part about instantiating a class, as well as how to invoke instance methods (functions for class objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 total ways you can call `drive_car()`

- Convert `drive_car()` into a [static method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/735978/11177720). This way you can call this via `car.drive_car()`
- Or, you instantiate the class `car` and then call `drive_car()` like so: `car().drive_car()`