# TypeError: is_peak() missing 1 required positional argument: 'start_time'

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I can't seem to figure out why my unittest is not running. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiI3M.png)

I am trying to test the methods in calculator class:

```
class Calculator():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def is_peak(self, start_time: str):
        time = start_time.split(':') 
        hour = time[0]
        int_hour = int(hour)
        if 6 <= int_hour < 18:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

This is the testcase for unittest:

```
class TestCalculator(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_time(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, Calculator.is_time('9:40'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `is_peak()` should be a static method since it is called without initializing the class.

Since no object is initialized, the `self` parameter in `is_peak()` becomes just like any other. This is why you're getting the positional argument error.

Try this in your class instead:

```
class Calculator():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def is_peak(start_time: str):
        time = start_time.split(':')  # Extracts the hour character from the string
        hour = time[0]
        int_hour = int(hour)
        if 6 <= int_hour < 18:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Related question: [Static methods in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the function call.

`self.assertEqual(True, Calculator.is_peak('9:40'))`

This should be like this:

`self.assertEqual(True, Calculator().is_peak('9:40'))`

Your unittest code should be like this:

```
class TestCalculator(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_peak(self):
        # testCase 1 (User enters a valid time in the peak hour)
        self.assertEqual(True, Calculator().is_peak('9:40'))

        # # testCase 2 (User enters a valid time in the off-peak hour)
        self.assertEqual(True, Calculator().is_peak('20:30'))
```

**Explanation:**

Why should we use `Calculator()` instead of `Calculator`?

If we want access full features of a class we have to create a object of a class by using `Calculator()`.

When make function call like this `Calculator.is_peak()` it consider `self` as a parameter but when we call like this `Calculator().is_peak()` it consider `self` as a class default parameter.

We can see the different behavior of class from below mentions snippets.

**`print(dir(Calculator.is_peak))`**

> `['__annotations__', '__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__kwdefaults__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']`

**`print(dir(Calculator().is_peak))`**

> `['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__func__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']`