# Inheritance: how to call method of parent class?

Tags: python, object-oriented-analysis

I made following 3 classes. `India` is parent class of `States` and `States` is parent class of `District`. I define 1 object of `District` class. When I try to run method of `India` class it gives an error. Please help me how to run it.

```
class India:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Country is India")
    def functionofindia(number):
        rvalue=number*2
        return rvalue   

    
class States(India):
    def __init__(self,nameofstate):
        super().__init__()
        print("state is {}".format(nameofstate))


class District(States):
    def __init__(self,nameofstate, nameofdistrict):
        super().__init__(nameofstate)
        print("District is {}".format(nameofdistrict))


HP=District("abc","xyz")
print(HP.functionofindia(2))
```

The Error is:

```
Country is India
state is abc
District is xyz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\practice\oops.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(HP.functionofindia(2))
TypeError: functionofindia() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Did you mean: `def functionofindia(self, number):`?

Comment: Having `States` extend `India` is backwards. You're creating something generic from a brand. You should be creating a brand from something generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a class method like this you should pass `self` as the first argument in the method definition. So your class India becomes:

```py
class India:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Country is India")
    def functionofindia(self, number):
        rvalue=number*2
        return rvalue
```

When the method is not relevant to any attribute of the class, you could also replace it with a static method. See more about static methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python). India with a static method:

```py
class India:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Country is India")

    @staticmethod
    def functionofindia(number):
        rvalue=number*2
        return rvalue
```

Comment: "When the method is not relevant to any attribute of the class, you could also replace it with a static method." Or more idiomatically, *don't make it a method at all*