# Class that holds variables and has methods?

Tags: python, class, object

I have a class like this:

```
class ErrorMessages(object): 
    """a class that holds all error messages and then presents them to the user)"""
    messages= []
    userStrMessages= ""

    def newError(self, Error): 
        self.userStrMessages+= Error

    def __str__(self):
        if self.messages.count() != 0: 
            i=0
            for thing in self.messages: 
               self.userStrMessages += self.messages[i] + "\n"
               i+=1
        return self.userStrMessages
```

this doesn't work when I call on it like this and wants 2 input variables, but that is just self and what i put into it?:

```
        ErrorMessages.newError(errormessage)
```

errormessage is a string

i have a (what i think is) a static class? (new to this and learned in swedish which makes this harder) it looks like this

```
class EZSwitch(object): 
    fileway= "G:/Other computers/Stationär Dator/Files/Pyhton Program/Scheman"
    fileway2= "Kolmården.txt"
    numberSchedules= 30
```

I thought i could make my errormessagclass like this but it also does things with methods. Like adds things to the list messages on newError. It doesnt seem to be possible or how would I do this?

Comment: Explain "doesn't work". What happens, what should happen? If there is an error message, show it as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: You aren't creating any instances of `ErrorMessages`.

Comment: `self.userStrMessages.count()` count what ? You need to pass argument.

Comment: oh, ehn i translated my code I meant to write messages.Count and not self.userStrMessages.count()

Comment: https://pynative.com/python-class-method-vs-static-method-vs-instance-method/

Comment: @MichaelButscher  it like this and wants 2 input variables and crashes. The message is: ´ErrorMessages.newError() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Error'´

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to call a method directly without making an object first then you'll have to make your method `newError()` a class method and then call it as you mentioned above.

```
@classmethod
def newError(self, Error): 
    self.userStrMessages+= Error

ErrorMessages.newError(errormessage)
```

Otherwise you can create an object first and then call the method as:

```
err_object = ErrorMessage()
err_object.newError(errormessage)
```

Comment: Gotcha, removing staticmethod from answer

Comment: Awesome! I can now add stuff to userStrMessages.

Comment: I added @classmethod to `def __str__(self)`  too, but when i operate the line: `self.userStrMessages += self.meddelanden[i] + "\n" ` it gives me the TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple.

Comment: self.meddelanden[I] is probably of type tuple then. Make sure it is string first.

Answer (score -2):

newError is an instance method.  You'd need to instantiate it and then call it:

```
myMessage = ErrorMessage()
myMessage.newError("important error message")
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python) about making it a static/class method, which would let you call it on the class without instantiation.

Comment: `ErrorMessage myMessage` doesn't look like Python to me.

Comment: Neither does `new ErrorMessage()`.

Comment: I am a slow pony today.